# NodeJS Request return JSON from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request

I've read a couple of posts about this here (callbacks) but I still don't really fully understand how to solve my problem. So I was hoping that somebody here could help me with mine and I would get it better.

Simple put I want the ID I get from the first request to be used for the second request.

I'm new to JavaScript and NodeJS in general.

```js
function idRequest(name) {
    var options = {
        ...
    };
    
    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200 && !error) {
           const info = JSON.parse(body);
           //console.log(info.accountId);
           return info.accountId;   
       }    
    }
    request(options, callback);
}

function requestById(accountId) {

    var options = {
        ...
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200 && !error) {
            const info = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(info);
        }   
      }
    
    request(options, callback);
}

var id = idRequest('..');
requestById(id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by returning a promise from the first function and inside it resolve the callback, so the once it is resolved , you can use it's then to trigger the second function

```
function idRequest(name) {
  var options = {
    ...
  };

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200 && !error) {
      const info = JSON.parse(body);
      //console.log(info.accountId);
      return info.accountId;
    }
  }
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(request(options, callback))

  })
}

function requestById(accountId) {

  var options = {
    ...
  };

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200 && !error) {
      const info = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(info);
    }
  }

  request(options, callback);
}

var id = idRequest('..').then(function(data) {
  requestById(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since callback is a async call, so `var id` will be `undefined`, when you call the `requestById(id);`

so either you can use the promise method, answered by @brk or you can call your `requestById(id)` function directly from the first callback.